# Failed to request access token for Fusion Tables API with Google Service Account

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have been successfully using Google API (via HTTP/REST, as well as using the .NET client library) with a Google Service Account to access the files in Google Drive.

Recently, I am exploring the Fusion Tables. I am able to use the API with user authorization via a web application. However, when I try to access it using Google Service Account under the same project, it failed with the below error, whenever I have **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables** in the scope:

> https:// www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
>   HTTP 401
>   {"error": "unauthorized_client",  "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }

The error goes away, when I remove https:// www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables and the same code block works fine with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive and other scopes.

I have checked and confirmed the "Fusion Tables API" is already enabled for my project at Google Developers Console. (Otherwise, my user authorization via a web application would not be working at the first place.)

Is there anything which I could have missed out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just come across this:
[Google drive service account and "Unauthorized client or scope in request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297710/google-drive-service-account-and-unauthorized-client-or-scope-in-request/32137852#32137852)

Even though it does not seems to be related at the first glance, it is indeed the same issue.

Problem resolved after removing `User = svcAcct,` from the below code block.

```
  ServiceAccountCredential credential;
  credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(svcAcct) {
      // User = svcAcct, *** removed ***
      Scopes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(scopes.Split(' '))
    }.FromCertificate(certificate)
  );
```

Hence, here is the general advise:

> DO NOT call **ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer** with **User = svcAcct** unnecessarily.
>
> Only do this when you are trying to impersonating a difference user
>   (with the condition that the appropriate setup has been correctly done
>   in Google Apps Admin Console).
>
> Even though it may not produce any error under certain cases, there
>   are some unexpected behaviors when including an email address of the
>   service account itself in the JWT claim set as the value of the "sub"
>   field.